# How to add authorization to a Contentful webhook so it triggers a GitHub action?

Tags: gatsby, github-actions, github-pages, contentful

I've got a simple Gatsby site that pulls some content from a Contentful CMS.  The repo is set up to publish to GitHub pages via an action that's triggered on commits to `main`.  That all works.

Now I'm trying to add a webhook to Contentful to trigger that action when new content is published.  I've created the webhook and added a secret header, putting `token` in the Key field and the personal access token from GitHub in the Value field.  When I test the webhook, I see the `token` field being sent to GitHub, but it always responds with a `404`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being an auth newbie, I now realize I wasn't setting up the header correctly.  Since the examples showed a `token` string before the personal access token, I used that as the header key, and put the PAT in the value field.  [This post](https://github.community/t/trigger-workflow-from-url/16416) helped me realize the obvious point that the header is called `Authorization`, so I needed to include that.  So I put `Authorization: token` in the Key field and the PAT in the Value field.

But that doesn't work either, because Contentful correctly doesn't allow colons in the key string.  You have to actually put `token`  (with a space) in the Value field, as a prefix to the PAT, which starts with `ghp_`.  The Value field's text is hidden, so you'll probably want to type out the `token ghp_...` string somewhere else and copy/paste into Contentful.  An ugly ASCII version of the dialog is shown below.

#### tl;dr

```
Key (required):
[Authorization                ]    

Value (required): 
[token ghp_a1b2c3456...       ]  (<-- this will show as just ****)
```